# Creating a permanent (fixed) conda environment

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, conda, environment

I need a permanent environment with fixed libraries for users to install for using a specific (scientific, open-source) software package (with minimal funding options). These libraries should not need to be updated in the foreseeable future. I have been unable to use a standard .yml file for this purpose due to the specific combination of libraries I'm using (I need python2 with very specific versions of VTK, Mayavi and PyQt4 to work properly; they will not work if I blindly install the latest versions)

I've tried `conda list --explicit` and this was working very well for some time (I made a list for both macOS and linux). However, today I was notified by a user that this conda list was no longer working for them (showing up as a HTTP 404 error when installing the environment on their new machine). Upon investigating further, it appears this was because a developer had removed one of the files I was referencing (Mayavi of a specific version).

If developers are simply deleting old packages at whim, this seems to defeat the entire purpose I was using `conda list --explicit` for. Is there anything else I can do?

I've considered the idea that I might have to host these static libraries somewhere with instructions for users to download and install properly? The downside is that this would require ~2 GB of storage. Along this line of logic, I've also tried `conda pack` but got back an error that it couldn't parse pip from conda libraries. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

**Update 1:** It was suggested I look into a `requirements.txt` file. I've since created one via `conda list --export > requirements.txt`. However, upon using it to create a new environment (via `conda create --name <envname> --file requirements.txt`), I get the following error:

```
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - openmpi==1.6.3=1
  - qt==4.8.7=1
  - pyqt==4.11.4=py27_4
```

Which is strange since these are all `anaconda/osx-64` channels (which I have activated)

(...cleaning up previous updates)

**Update 4:** I've been informed in the comments that the `requirements.txt` is functionally equivalent to `conda list --explicit`. So now my problem is now summarized:

1. `conda list --explicit`: requires that developers keep their libraries online. However, as they tend to delete older libraries at whim, this method is not stable for longtime use.
2. `pip freeze > requirements.txt`: does not actually add all of dependencies in environment to the text file; for example, PyQt4 and Qt4 were completely absent (I still don't understand why).
3. `conda list --export > requirements.txt`: this does show all dependencies in the text file, but then some of these dependencies can not be found upon re-installing the environment via the `requirements.txt` file (for example, `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: openmpi==1.6.3=1, qt==4.8.7=1, pyqt==4.11.4=py27_4`)
4. hosting specific tarballs: it appears my only option then is to download all of these dependencies myself (exact versions of each library in `tar.gz` format and provide them for the user. The downside is this will take upwards of 2 GB of memory. I should also restate that this is for open-source scientific software, so funding for things like this is an issue.

   Can anyone recommend any websites that are good to host a collection of tarballs (or should I host them on a workstation with ssh instructions, etc)? Also, what instructions do I need to follow to reproduce a conda environment from a folder of tarballs?

Comment: Why not create a `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Is this different from the outputs of conda list --explicit? For example, the file that I'm currently using has lines for each library (such as: https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/osx-64/mayavi-4.6.2-py27hdde6e19_4.tar.bz2)

Comment: @bigbounty I've updated my post using your advice, and ran into a problem with the requirements.txt file initiated environment

Comment: You should use `pip freeze` to `requirements.txt` file

Comment: Thank you @bigbounty - I've updated my post (Update 2) to show the error outputs of using the requirements.txt from `pip freeze`, which are different from the previous method

Comment: `requirements.txt` file is functionally equivalent to the output of `conda list --explicit`. The root problem is access to the zipped up packages, so if you need to make those available in perpetuity, then yes, you'll need to download them and host them somewhere. If you haven't cleaned the user's environment lately, you can get the `.tar.gz` file for the missing package from their cache folder.

Comment: @darthbith thank you for clarifying. Do you have any idea why a conflict keeps emerging when I try to reinstall this environment via pip or conda (as seen in Update 2 and 3 above)? Additionally, do you have a reference for how I should instruct them to compile an environment strictly from a folder of `.tar.gz` files?

Comment: @ees Probably the conflict is because Python 2 is no longer supported and packages are dropping/deleting old versions that they don't need anymore. I'm not sure how to specify a whole folder of files, but if you point conda install at a single file .tar.gz, I believe it will just install that file. You can write a script from there. Honestly though, you're probably better off trying to get off of Python 2 if that's at all possible. I also maintain an open-source project, so I'm aware of the funding problems, but this will just keep happening for as long as you support Python 2...

Comment: You could hypothetically create your own channel on anaconda.org and upload/host the tarballs there more or less indefinitely, and that would certainly make it easier for people to install `conda install -c your-channel-name env.yaml` but I'm not sure if the licenses of the various packages would allow you to do that.

Comment: @darthbith that's an interesting idea that I've never looked into. I'm reading up on this now; do you mean to say that only packages I own (have created) should be placed in a new conda channel, or are there exceptions? If I went down this route, then legally, would I need to get permission from each package's original owner? (also, I'm stuck with Python2 for this project since the 10k line user interface is written in PyQt4)

Comment: @ees Yes, that's what I was thinking. On the other hand, conda-forge packages and distributes most things without permission (AFAIK), so maybe it wouldn't be a problem as long as you include the license. Now that I think of it, the packages you need may already be on anaconda.org, just in a different channel than you've used before (and possibly with a different build hash, but might still be compatible).